# execute() hangs in psycopg2 when selecting a json-type column

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 to query a PostgreSQL database in Python. When trying to select a column of type `json`, the execute statement hangs and never finishes. The query runs fine when selecting any other columns. It also executes without problems when run from pgAdmin.

This is the offending piece of code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT data FROM public.config WHERE account_name = %s LIMIT 1;", [accountName])
```

where `data` is the `json` column. Running

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

returns `wait_event: ClientRead` and `state: idle` for the corresponding connection.

Changing `data` to `data::TEXT` or using any other of the available JSON operators as a workaround does not help unfortunately.

Any ideas on what to try next? Thanks!

Comment: You have not supplied a value for the `%s` placeholder.  It should be: `cur.execute("SELECT data FROM public.config WHERE account_name = %s LIMIT 1;", ['<some_name>'])`

Comment: Sorry, the parameter is supplied in the actual code and just went missing during copy-paste. It also doesn't work without any parameter binding though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: To question add answers to following: 1) What is the type for `account_name`? 2) Postgres version and psycopg2 versions? 3) What does the Postgres log show if you crank up(temporarily) `log_statement` to `all` in postgresql.conf?

Answer (score 0):

When one is looking for information in a database, the problem is usually in the selection criteria and not in the returned data (with the exception that the volume of these has a considerable size).

I suggest to try **EXPLAIN SELECT data FROM public.config WHERE account_name = %s LIMIT 1;**

Greetings, Alejandro

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the EXPLAIN does not yield any useful information.

Comment: Can you share the EXPLAIN result? To show the query plan that postgresql uses in this case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).